# Terminal cyrillic problem

Tags: command-line, cyrillic

When I ran the `xclock` command in the terminal, I always received the following warning:

```bsh
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
```

I edited my  `~/.bashrc` file added the following line to the end:

```bsh
export LC_ALL=C
```

And after that my console got weird behavior - I can delete initial characters describing the current user and the path where it is located.

It happens if I write something in Cyrillic. When I am trying to insert the first Cyrillic letter, all I wrote before replaced by `�` symbol. Then I can delete initial characters in my console continuing to press `backspace` button

[image]

**Why does the variable `LC_ALL` affect my terminal and how can I solve the problem with the warning `xclock` without harm to the terminal?**

Comment: "Why does the variable LC_ALL affect my terminal" – because it defines the applications' (including the shell's) belief of the terminal's character set; from presumably UTF-8 to ASCII (the basic 7-bit English letters, digits and essential punctuation only).

Comment: "how can I" – don't set LC_ALL this way. If xclock's warning really bothers you, redirect it to /dev/null, or create a wrapper script that modifies LC_ALL only for xclock and not for anything else.

Comment: @egmont , ok, I understand the part of your answer about wrapper script. But what I must redirect to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Not "must" but "can".  It's one possibility. You can get rid of the warning by redirecting xclock's standard error to /dev/null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything turned out really as the user `@egmont` said.

When variable `LC_ALL` defined as `C` it sets the encoding for all applications presumably to ASCII(in general, it is only important, that the encoding is changed to another, which does not support the Cyrillic)

Initially `LC_ALL` hasn't been defined. If this is the case for you, you can check it out by typing:

```bsh
echo $LC_ALL
```

The variable is empty if you will get an empty line.

**The** `xclock`**'s warning as I understand appears because of this - due to the lack of explicitly specified encoding**

If you set `LC_ALL` to `C` as stated in most internet tips, you clearly specify the encoding. And this encoding is not `UTF-8`

**For problem solution you must explicitly specify the encoding which supports Cyrillic.** You can do it by adding the next line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```